# Data table operations with multiple group by variable sets

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that I would like to perform group-by operations on, but would like to retain the null variables and use different group-by variable sets.

A toy example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(
        id = sample(c("US", "Other"), 25, replace = TRUE), 
        loc = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 25, replace = TRUE), 
        index = runif(25)
        )
```

I would like to find the sum of `index` by all combinations of the key variables (including the null set). The concept is analogous to "grouping sets" in Oracle SQL, here is an example of my current workaround:

```
rbind(
  DT[, list(id = "", loc = "", sindex = sum(index)), by = NULL],
  DT[, list(loc = "", sindex = sum(index)), by = "id"],
  DT[, list(id = "", sindex = sum(index)), by = "loc"],
  DT[, list(sindex = sum(index)), by = c("id", "loc")]
)[order(id, loc)]
       id loc      sindex
 1:           11.54218399
 2:         A  2.82172063
 3:         B  0.98639578
 4:         C  2.89149433
 5:         D  3.93292900
 6:         E  0.90964424
 7: Other      6.19514146
 8: Other   A  1.12107080
 9: Other   B  0.43809711
10: Other   C  2.80724742
11: Other   D  1.58392886
12: Other   E  0.24479728
13:    US      5.34704253
14:    US   A  1.70064983
15:    US   B  0.54829867
16:    US   C  0.08424691
17:    US   D  2.34900015
18:    US   E  0.66484697
```

Is there a preferred "data table" way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you really want the results in a `data.table`, what you do here is fine. If you're just going to look at the results, a tabular format, with your cross-classifying variables on the margins, is much better: `stable <- tapply(DT$index,list(DT$id,DT$loc),sum); mstable <- rbind(cbind(stable,apply(stable,1,sum)),c(apply(stable,2,sum),sum(stable)))`. By the way, please use `set.seed` when generating random data for an example.

Comment: Oh, it's actually simpler than that, since `addmargins` works: `addmargins(stable)`

Comment: [Oracle GROUPING SETS](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#grouping_sets) could be done by a data.table high level functions, no internals required, the similar what you did it. I recommend to fill a feature request for that feature.

Comment: Just for the record, there is an open FR [data.table#1377](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1377). Also you can find `rollup` generic function example in this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32938770/2490497) and a little more generic [rollup.data.table](https://github.com/jangorecki/data.cube/blob/dba1ba8ca4203021ecc2cd4442d58c142a40fc76/R/rollup.R#L11) method. Still they don't directly answer *grouping sets* so I'm just putting in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/1bc0553449c99a44015130615aa1fc40a5771774) commit, this is now possible with the dev version of `data.table` with `cube` or `groupingsets`:

```
library("data.table")
# data.table 1.10.5 IN DEVELOPMENT built 2017-08-08 18:31:51 UTC
#   The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors): https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way
#   Documentation: ?data.table, example(data.table) and browseVignettes("data.table")
#   Release notes, videos and slides: http://r-datatable.com

cube(DT, list(sindex = sum(index)), by = c("id", "loc"))
#        id loc      sindex
#  1:    US   B  0.54829867
#  2:    US   A  1.70064983
#  3: Other   B  0.43809711
#  4: Other   E  0.24479728
#  5: Other   C  2.80724742
#  6: Other   A  1.12107080
#  7:    US   E  0.66484697
#  8:    US   D  2.34900015
#  9: Other   D  1.58392886
# 10:    US   C  0.08424691
# 11:    NA   B  0.98639578
# 12:    NA   A  2.82172063
# 13:    NA   E  0.90964424
# 14:    NA   C  2.89149433
# 15:    NA   D  3.93292900
# 16:    US  NA  5.34704253
# 17: Other  NA  6.19514146
# 18:    NA  NA 11.54218399

groupingsets(DT, j = list(sindex = sum(index)), by = c("id", "loc"), sets = list(character(), "id", "loc", c("id", "loc")))
#        id loc      sindex
#  1:    NA  NA 11.54218399
#  2:    US  NA  5.34704253
#  3: Other  NA  6.19514146
#  4:    NA   B  0.98639578
#  5:    NA   A  2.82172063
#  6:    NA   E  0.90964424
#  7:    NA   C  2.89149433
#  8:    NA   D  3.93292900
#  9:    US   B  0.54829867
# 10:    US   A  1.70064983
# 11: Other   B  0.43809711
# 12: Other   E  0.24479728
# 13: Other   C  2.80724742
# 14: Other   A  1.12107080
# 15:    US   E  0.66484697
# 16:    US   D  2.34900015
# 17: Other   D  1.58392886
# 18:    US   C  0.08424691
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a generic function that you can feed in a dataframe and a vector of dimensions you wish to group by, and it will return the sum of all numeric fields grouped by those dimensions.

```
rollSum = function(input, dimensions){
   #cast dimension inputs to character in case a dimension input is numeric 
   for (x in 1:length(dimensions)){
       input[[eval(dimensions[x])]] = as.character(input[[eval(dimensions[x])]])
    }
    numericColumns = which(lapply(input,class) %in% c("integer", "numeric")) 
    output = input[,lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = eval(dimensions),
    .SDcols = numericColumns]
    return(output)
}
```

So then you can create a list of your different group by vectors:

```
groupings = list(c("id"),c("loc"),c("id","loc"))
```

And then use it with lapply and rbindlist in the way of:

```
groupedSets = rbindlist(lapply(groupings, function(x){
    return(rollSum(DT,x))}), fill = TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

using `dplyr`, an adaption of this should work, if I understand your question correctly.

```
sum <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(vs, am) %>%
  summarise(Sum=sum(mpg))
```

I didnt check how it treats the missung values though,but it should just make another group of them (last group).